# How to encode .mkv video to .mp4 in ffmpeg while retaining the video subtitles and add additioinal watermark?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, encoding

I want to encode .mkv video to .mp4 using ffmpeg while retaining the subtitle in .mkv format and add additioinal watermark, the current technique that i know is

this will convert the .mkv video to .mp4

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -vf subtitles=video.mkv video.mp4
```

and to add watermark i use this command

```
fmpeg -i video.mkv -i smiley.png -filter_complex 'overlay=W-w-15:H-h-15' video.mp4
```

But this is a long process, are there any alternative to mix the code? or make it a single process... (one way) encode

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i video.mkv -i smiley.png \
-filter_complex "overlay=W-w-15:H-h-15,subtitles=video.mkv[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a video.mp4
```

The subtitles filter works on the output produced by the overlay filter, and so is separated by a comma.

Comment: I get this error "bash: no matches found: [v]"

Comment: Enclose in quotes. `"[v]"`